# Are there materials that just change the speed of light?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, speed-of-light, refraction

Maxwell's equations in medium without charges read
\begin{align}
0&=\nabla\cdot D\,,\\
0&=\nabla\cdot B\,,\\
0&=\nabla\times E + \dot B\,,\\
0&=\nabla\times H - \dot D\,.
\end{align}
Here, $D = \varepsilon E$ and $\mu H = B$, with $\varepsilon$ and $\mu$ the relative permittivity and permeability of the medium.

One may derive wave equations for $E$ and $B$ of the form
\begin{align}
0&=\square E\,,\\
0&=\square B\,,
\end{align}
if $\varepsilon$ and $\mu$ are constant. However, when they vary in space, derivatives of $\mu$ and $\varepsilon$ spoil this nice relationship. Even so, if the medium is slowly changing as a function of space, we can usually neglect derivatives of $\mu$ and $\varepsilon$, leading to the interpretation of $1/\sqrt{\mu\varepsilon}$ as the effective speed of light. My question is whether there are inhomogeneous media for which this interpretation is exact, i.e. for which changing $\mu$ and $\varepsilon$ may be exactly interpreted as changing $c$ in the wave equation.

Comment: Various GRIN lenses spring to mind (graded refractive index). Cladding in multimode optical fibres also operates in this regime, though one usually solves the Maxwells equations in full

Comment: Saying exact is problematic though, nothing is exact, even Maxwells equations in medium have to be modified sometimes

Comment: Note that according to the usual definition, $B = \mu H$, not the other way around.

Comment: @Javier thank you for catching that!

Comment: @Cryo thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can have a position-dependent  speed of light
$$
c_{\rm local}= \frac 1{\sqrt{\mu\epsilon}}
$$
without much else happening  as long as you keep the medium's wave impedence
$$
Z_{\rm local}= \sqrt{\frac{\mu}{\epsilon}}
$$
constant.  This is suggested by the [Riemann-Siberstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Silberstein_vector) rewriting of Maxwell's equations in which the ${\boldsymbol \Psi}^{\pm} ={\bf E}\pm iZ_{\rm local}{\bf H}$ parts of the E&M field decouple when $Z$ is constant. The "curl" Maxwell become
$$
i\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \Psi_i^{\pm}= c_{\rm local}\epsilon_{ijk} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} \Psi^{\pm}_k,
$$
and the $\nabla \cdot B=\nabla\cdot D=0$ equations follow from these when the frequency is non-zero.
Of course it is rather difficult to keep $Z$ constant as many transparant materials have large $\epsilon$ but not many dielectrics have large $\mu$'s

Comment: Thank you! This is precisely the kind of argument I was looking for!

Answer (score -1):

The relation $c_{medium}=1/\epsilon\mu$ is not exact if the medium is not homogeneous. The question is how exact do you want it to be?

You apparently knew that this would be the answer.

Note that at atomic scale no medium is homogenous.